# Flutter Android revenuecat subscription status is active even after expiration

Tags: android, flutter, revenuecat

I am using **Revenuecat** (purchases_flutter: **^3.7.0**) plugin in my Flutter **Android** app. However I noticed, even if the (test) subscription has been ended the code shows it is still active.

I am using the following method to determine whether the subscription is active or not.

```
static isUserSubscribed() async {
  bool _isSubscribed = false;
  await Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(false);
  await Purchases.setup(revenueCatId);
  if (userId != null) {
      await Purchases.setup(revenueCatId, appUserId: userId);
      PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getPurchaserInfo();
  if (purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["Ads Free"] != null &&
      purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["Ads Free"].isActive != null &&
      purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["Ads Free"].isActive) {

  //  it comes here even though the subscription has been expired 
     _isSubscribed = true; 
  } 
  return _isSubscribed;
}
```

I noticed, when I do test purchase and even after the subscription has been ended the above method returns true always. I even restarted the app and logged out and even clear the memory too.

If I go to **revenucat.com** and remove the user by searching the email address then it start returning false. My test subscription was expired in the morning around 9:00 AM but in the evening also it showing active in the app.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A couple things I see from the code: 1) `Purchases.setup` should only be called once at application startup - you may be configuring multiple instances of Purchases having it in that function and checking subscription status on the wrong instance. 2) It should be sufficient to just check `purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["Ads Free"].isActive`, all the other conditions are redundant and sometimes chained logic plays tricks on us debugging.

Comment: I am calling this method in the initState() as and when the app starts. But I will double check to make sure I am not calling at multiple places. Also I will  change the if condition and let you know. Thank you for your time.